# Apache Camel: Add bean to registry for custom poll strategy

Tags: java, spring, apache, apache-camel, camel-ftp

I need to implement a custom `PollingConsumerPollStrategy` implementation on a route inside a `RouteBuilder`. The examples I found use spring to create a bean, but i am not using Spring in my project.

How do i add `MyPollStrategy` to registry and use it as pollStrategy=#myPoll ?

```
public class MyFtpServiceBuilder extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        // Want to add to below route &pollStrategy=#myPoll

        from("sftp://tmpserver.example.com:22//tmp/testfolder?password=xxxxxx&username=tmpuser")
            .routeId("testRoute")
            .to("file:C:/tmp/testfolder")

    }

    private class MyPollStrategy implements PollingConsumerPollStrategy {
        public boolean begin(Consumer consumer, Endpoint endpoint) {
            return true;
        }
        public void commit(Consumer consumer, Endpoint endpoint, int polledMessages) {
            if (polledMessages > maxPolls) {
                maxPolls = polledMessages;
            }
            latch.countDown();
        }
        public boolean rollback(Consumer consumer, Endpoint endpoint, int retryCounter, Exception cause) throws Exception {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As i was using the `org.apache.camel.main.Main`, I could not figure out a way to create a SimpleRegistry as Claus mentioned and pass it to the main object.

Just found out that there is a method `bind` in `Main` class to pass bean name and bean object.

```
Main main = new Main();
main.addRouteBuilder(new MyTestRouteBuilder());
main.enableHangupSupport();
main.bind("myPoll", new MyPollStrategy());
main.run();
```

Comment: Can you include your entire class?

Answer (score 3):

You can create an instance of `SimpleRegistry` where you can add your custom bean. And then pass in the simple registry instance to where you create CamelContext with the `new DefaultCamelContext(myRegistry)` constructor.

If you have a copy of Camel in Action book, see the beans chapter, it explain all about this in more details.

On the web site there is a little details at: http://camel.apache.org/registry.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer Claus. I am using `MainSupport` for starting the route. How do i create an instance of `SimpleRegistry` and add to the `MainSupport` ?

Comment: I am stuck on the same thing. I have to create a new route builder within the route builder in order to attach the registry.